# Numpy Array Value Error, looking for specific element in Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have loaded an Image of the Array shape (1024, 1152, 3).
Then reshaping it into 2D:

```
x, y, z = img.shape
img_2d = img.reshape(x*y,z)
```

The second row contains values of the RGB System (e.g. `print(img_2d[70000,:])` gives the Output `[171 135 115]`.
I now want to assign each RGB Color Code to one integer (e.g. [255 0 0] = 1 for red) and therefore iterate the Array with a Loop:

```
for i in img_2d:
     if img_2d[i,0] == 255:
            print(img_2d[i,1])
```

However, I'm getting that cryptic Error that i don't understand:

***ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()***

Anybody knowing what's wrong?
(Sorry but I am a beginner and not a programmer either.)

Comment: This `img_2d[i,0]` is an array so `img_2d[i,0] == 255` is comparing an array of values to a single number. Hence the error.

Comment: But e.g. `img_2d[70000,0]` is giving me one number (171) as an integer as an Output (uint8). So how am I supposed to compare these two values then?

Comment: Oh wait I just realized, what's this supposed to be `for i in img_2d`??? Maybe you meant to use `range` and `shape` here?

Comment: No i'm fairly certain that's where the mistake is. Perhaps you're talking about a previous comment which I deleted but read my last comment before this.

Comment: You need to use `for i in range(img_2d.shape[0])` OR `if i[0] == 255:`

Comment: "You need to use for i in range(img_2d.shape[0])"  that just came to mind right now too! im checking that

Comment: that solved it, thank you so much SilverSlash!